# Grafana SQL Query, convert string to number

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

Grafana Query

```
Select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as time_sec,
    metric_value as value,
    'Metric Value' as metric
from lumenis_db.telemetry
where $__timeFilter(created_at)
```

Receive the following error:

```
Value column must have numeric datatype, column: value type: string
```

How can I Cast / Convert metric_value from string to number via the query?

**EDIT**

My SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE lumenis_db.telemetry (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
created_at DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
device_type VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
device_serial VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
metric_name VARCHAR(35) NULL,
metric_value VARCHAR(35) NULL
);
```

Comment: Is `metric_value` a number stored as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `metric_value` contains values which are numbers stored as `String` then you can use MySQL's `CONVERT` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as time_sec,
    CONVERT(metric_value, UNSIGNED) as value,
    'Metric Value' as metric
FROM lumenis_db.telemetry
WHERE $__timeFilter(created_at)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) is the documentation for `CONVERT` function.

Comment: I get this: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED_INTEGER) as value,
    'Metric Value' as metric
FROM lumenis_db.telem' at line 2

Comment: @user829174 try now?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) as time_sec,
    CAST(metric_value as SIGNED integer) as value,
    'Metric Value' as metric
FROM lumenis_db.telemetry
WHERE $__timeFilter(created_at)
```

did the trick